# Visual Studio 'Script Documents' not showing

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am having an issues with a MVC visual Studio 2012 project.  My 'Script Documents' doesnt show in solution explorer anymore.  I am using IE 9 to debug. I made sure that the debugging is not disabled in IE and have tried going to tools import export reset environment setting. I have added this line to my javascript to try and force it to debug   debugger; and it doesnt work. I have tried browse with google set as default then browse with IE set as default and that didnt work either.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed the problem I did a visual studio 2012 repair it now has the script documents and also I am able to put in break points. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a possible VS2017 answer using IE (yes, our customers still primarily use IE)

Under Start->Web Browser, see if it's set. Mine wasn't set to anything but IE was starting anyway. I changed it to a default of IE and now Script Documents is showing again and typescript/javascript debugging is working